# There are possible way of dividing two float numbers which was casted from unsigned int make negative float result?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, int, unsigned

```
unsigned int deltaTime = now() - last();
unsigned int freq = getFreq();
float timeOfGap = float(deltaTime) / float(freq);

ASSERT(0.0f <= timeOfGap, "WHAT?");
```

I got a really weired result from my program. I didn't catch a scene which is happened. But I have a log which said that really raised at least multiple times.

There are possible way of dividing between two float numbers which was casted from unsigned int make negative float result?

---

OK, thank you guys. I'm glad to see your attentions.
Let me try to add some descriptions about it. It'll be helpful for you.

I'm working for an online game, and this situation was raised rarely but frequently while hundreds of million times game was serving. I can't debug or catch the exact shot, but it is logged on the db error messages.

The timeOfGap should be NaN as you noticed, but the log didn't alert the value exactly. The timeOfGap is accumulated like below;

```
mTotalFrameRateTimeAsASecond += timeOfGap;
```

And this program logs mTotalFrameRateTimeAsASecond, that was a negative value. But except this sign of value was a negative, it is correct value. Meaning, it point time as look as good if I divide the final value with a framerate. A hypothetical play time was 500 sec, it is -30000(with 60 framerate per sec).

Comment: Have you tried to printf your `timeOfGap`? Maybe it is NAN.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is not negative, but a `NAN`. `0.0f <= NAN` is `false`. It may happen if both operands are zero.

Comment: Ok, probably you right. And one other question, NaN is possible to accumulate correctly?

Comment: @hey: What do you mean by accumulate correctly? Any arithmetic operation on NaN is a NaN again. Any comparison even `NaN==NaN` or `NaN!=NaN` is false.

Comment: As I mentioned above I got normal size number after sums every timeOfGap. But it was just negative.

Comment: @hey: Then there is probably some other error in the code. You should debug or you should trace/print the values of `float(deltaTime)` and `float(freq)` if `0.0f <= timeOfGap` does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

The value `nan` will not compare to anything successfully. So if you have:

```
float f = 0.0 / 0.0;

assert(f > 0 || f <= 0);
```

The assertion will fail!

Comment: Inf will compare successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This should find the problem:

```
unsigned int deltaTime = now() - last();
unsigned int freq = getFreq();
float timeOfGap = float(deltaTime) / float(freq);
char s[50] ;
sprintf (s, "WHAT? %u/%u < 0!", deltaTime, freq);

ASSERT(0.0f <= timeOfGap, s);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a simple test to verify the cast from unsigned int to float.

Try this :

```
unsigned int toto = 0xFFFFFFFF; 
float convertedToto = float(toto);
```

`convertedToto` will equals -1 if the convertion (unsigned int -> float) is in fact (int -> float). You should get 2*10e31 with a proper conversion.

Comment: Two mistakes: (i) 0x80000000 is not -1 in any system -- you mean -(2^31). (ii) 2e31 means 2 * 10^31, not 2^31.

Comment: Get a grip rockeye! `2*10e31` means `2*10*10^31`.